# In Android flavors Activity not getting changed based on flavor. Only main package activity is called

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I have created 2 flavors(one and two) and one main package as you can see in image which i have shared. These three flavors has a separate three MainActivity.class. 
when i change the flavor i am trying to change the textView content from MainActivity.class of its flavor, but it's not getting changed. Only the layout is getting replaced as per the flavor not the class.

For example, i set current flavor as one and set textView content as "one" from MainActivity.class its not getting changed but it takes the MainActivity.class of main package and the layout is working taken based on the flavor.

project structure image

[image]

Comment: have you added .java files folder for different flavour in sourceset in app.gradle?

Comment: Yes i have added. Please see the above image for your reference.

Comment: i mean can you ss your build.gradle where source set is defined.

Comment: Files with same name (and package) can either be present in your main folder or corresponding build flavors.

Comment: @SarthakMittal sorry i not able to get you, can you share me any link or explain in deep or any ref.. Thanks!

Comment: @MuthuS see this: https://github.com/SarthakM9/TodoApp/blob/73894da8cc525db475b191a0a4518964c1920855/app/src/main/java/com/showcase/todoapp/TodoApplication.java#L26

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Only the layout is getting replaced as per the flavor not the class.

Because the MainActivity.java of "main" is used every time.

The package name must be same in the other two modules.

Java files are not replaced so, you can remove MainActivity of "main".

Comment: I am not sure i got understand your point. Can you be more specific? I was thinking that not be possible to remove the MainActivity of main. Thanks!

Comment: M, If i create same package name and class name studio wont allow this conflict.

Comment: Yes, the java classes are not replaced, so you can delete MainActivity from "main" and try.

Comment: M,  Hi your solution is worked but in different way. See the image link of my project structure https://imgur.com/a/cOcyC. I want SecondActivity to be imported in MainActivity automatically when I change the flavor. Currently i have to manually change the import of secondActivity in MainActivity whenever i change the flavor. Thanks!

Comment: keep the package structure same. You can provide different applicationId to different flavors in build.gradle.

Comment: Without applicationId we are able to achieve this now. Is it mandatory? If yes share me some links about this to explore more on this. This is first time am using flavor, and thanks for your kind support. Thanks!

Comment: depends on your usage, as you were keeping package names different so i suggested to change applicationId instead.

Comment: We want maintain single applicationId. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Make a manifest file for your specific flavour that overrides the new activity for the flavour as follows:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<application>


    <!-- Tutorial activity -->
    <activity android:name="com.colan.flavortest.MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.colan.newtwo.MainActivity"
        tools:node="remove" />
    <activity-alias
        android:name="com.colan.newtwo.MainActivity"
        android:targetActivity="com.colan.flavortest.MainActivity"
        tools:replace="android:targetActivity"/>

</application>
</manifest>
```